# What does [^] match in C# regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm looking at someone else's regex... I can make out I'm dealing with a positive lookbehind, but I'm not sure what it's supposed to match: `(?<=[^])\t{2,}|(?<=[>])`.

I know `[stuff]` matches any character among *s*, *t*, *u*, and *f*. And I know `[^stuff]` matches any character *not* among those.

But what does `[^]` mean? I guess it could mean "anything not of length zero", i.e. "anything". But why wouldn't one just use some expansion on the simple `.` expression (to also capture newlines)?

**Update:**

Per Wikter's comment, `[^]` alone isn't valid. But that still leaves me wondering what this thing is supposed to do...

To me, an intuitive reading is...

`(?<=[^])` - look behind for whatever `[^]` matches

`\t{2,}` - then find two or more tabs

`|` - if there's not a match for that...

`(?<=[>])` - ...look behind for a `>` character.

Where is my interpretation missing the mark?

Comment: It is an invalid pattern as in majority of regex flavors other than ECMAScript. It will throw *`Unterminated [] set`* exception. To match any char, use `(?s:.)` (a `.` pattern with `RegexOptions.Singleline` option).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, you're right, the expression I gave wouldn't compile. I added more context from the source regex: `(?<=[^])\t{2,}|(?<=[>])`.

Comment: Yes, so the answer to "What does [^] match in C# regex?" is it does not match anything since it is an invalid pattern. It is not even tried at all, it fails at the parsing stage. And `[^>]` is a negated character class that matches any char but `>`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew feel free to drop that in an answer, and I'll accept it. Any further guidance on my misinterpretation of the regex (updated above) would also be appreciated!

Comment: This actually does compile in LINQPad, because .NET interprets the `]` following the `^` as a literal, so this whole thing becomes a big character class of anything except `]`, `)`, `\t`, `{`, etc. until the final `]`, all wrapped up in a lookbehind. But of course, I don't think that's the intent.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm wondering... Wouldn't it (the regex-compiler) *try* to make sense out of it and make a character class of **all** the letters up to the final `]`, after the `>`? It seems to compile in ideone...

Comment: @p.s.w.g yeah, even if that's the intent, it's weird that the characters are ordered in a way that reads like regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[^]` does not match anything since it is an invalid pattern. It is not even tried at all, it fails at the parsing stage. The `[^>]`, on the other hand, is a negated character class that matches any char but `>`.

The `[^]` is an invalid pattern in the majority of regex flavors other than ECMAScript. It will throw `Unterminated [] set` exception in .NET.

To match any char, use `(?s:.)` (a `.` pattern with `RegexOptions.Singleline` option).

The `(?<=[^])\t{2,}|(?<=[>])` pattern represents a single positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with `[^])\t{2,}|(?<=[>]` pattern, which is a *negated character class* matching any single char but `]`, `)`, tab, `{`, `2`, `,`, `}`, `|`, `(`, `?`, `<`, `=`, `[`, `>`. All the chars from the `[^` to the last `]` are "negated" because the first `]` after `^` is considered a literal `]` symbol.

You may see the [regex demo here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5b%5e%5d%29%5ct%7b2%2c%7d%7c%28%3f%3c%3d%5b%3e%5d%29&i=s) where it matches a location after `S`:

[image]

Basically, you need to always watch out for characters that are not word chars, and to play it safe, you may escape all non-word chars.

*Inside a character class*, there are only 4 chars that are "special":

```
^
]
\
-
```

If you want to avoid misunderstanding, always escape them.

If you want to show off before you boss/customer, note that you do not have to escape them if...

- `-` : if it appears at the end/start of the character class, or between a char and a valid range/shorthand character class, and if it is not part of a character class subtraction construct
- `]` : if  it appears right at the beginning of the character class AND it is not the only char in the character class
- `^` - if it is not the first char in the positive character class.

And `\` must **always** be escaped.

Comment: Where are you seeing [^>] in the given pattern? If you're talking about a single character class that happens to contain a >, say so.

Comment: @BoltClock It is in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46588130/what-does-match-in-c-sharp-regex/46588503#comment80129827_46588130). Actually, I just wanted to supply an example of a valid simple negated character class.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think you're looking at `[>]` rather than `[^>]`.